# Session value gets deleted after redirecting with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, session, redirect

I have implemented Ajax to login in wordpress project. After the successful login, user is redirected to my account page with JavaScript. In this case session value gets deleted and user is again redirected to normal login page. While logging in from this normal login page, session value works perfect.

I have started session in config file as well as `header.php` and also in php file that Ajax calls. Also tried without `session_start();` as well but no luck, on the Ajax PHP file, config file is already included so there is no need to `session_start();` on this page.

How to resolve the session issue?

Comment: Can you show us some more code from all your files?. Are you for example sure you always use your `session_start()` above the `<html>` tag?

Comment: Thanks 1ntello for your reply.
What I have done is pass username ans password with ajax and on successful login redirect to my account page with javascript with this code
window.location.href = redirurl;
As we have used session_start on config file we have not used session_start on php ajax file which is working for normal login page